# Google App Engine - Recommended approach for querying by Ids

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

Anyone can recommend the better approach for querying entities by multiple ids from GAE HRD datastore ?

1.

```
mgr = getEntityManager();           
Query dbQuery = mgr.createQuery("SELECT FROM CustomEntity as CustomEntity WHERE id IN (:ids)");
dbQuery.setParameter("ids", results.getIds());
return (List<CustomEntity>) dbQuery.getResultList();
```

2.

```
List<Key> customEntityKeys = new ArrayList<Key>();
for (String id : results.getIds()) {
    customEntityKeys.add(KeyFactory.createKey("CustomEntity", id));
}

mgr = getEntityManager();
JPADatastoreBridge jpaBridge = new JPADatastoreBridge();
List<CustomEntity> customEntities = new ArrayList<CustomEntity>();

Map<Key,Entity> customEntityMap = datastore.get(customEntityKeys);
for (Entity customEntityEntity : customEntityMap.values()) {
    customEntities.add((CustomEntity) jpaBridge.getJPAFromEntity(customEntityEntity, mgr, CustomEntity.class));                 
}
return customEntities;
```

In "better approach" i mean mainly performance wise. also, if there is another way I'll be happy to hear about it.
Thanks.

p.s.
Im using JPA as my persistance method. Not sure if this really matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about most of the code, but if you're asking whether you should use `Query("SELECT.... WHERE ID IN....")` or `datastore.get(...)`, the second is *much, much* better. Gets are significantly more efficient than queries with the App Engine datastore - not to mention the fact that they are always strongly consistent, whereas non-ancestor queries are only eventually consistent.